# Ошибка в JavaScript+Jquery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как исправить подобную ошибку?

Вид подключения:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Сама ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (main.js:112)
>       at n (jquery.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith (jquery.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.C (jquery.js:2)

Ошибка в main

```
 if (!IE)
 {
     var admin = $("#admin");
     if ($.cookie("top") < 0)
     {
        $.cookie("top", 0);
     }
     admin.animate({"left" : $.cookie("left") + "px", "top" : $.cookie("top") + "px"}, 1000);

    $("#admin").draggable({ scroll: true,
            stop: function(e,ui) {
                $.cookie("top", ui.position.top);
                $.cookie("left", ui.position.left);
            }
      });
 }
 else
 {
    $("#admin").draggable({ scroll: true});
 }
```

Comment: вы код `main.js` покажите

Comment: @ThisMan добавил. Ошибку подчеркивает в условии и пишет "Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function" (4ая строчка)

Comment: нужно дополнительно добавить ссылку на код, который добавит этот `$.cookie` по умолчанию он не входит в jquery, это отдельный плагин

Comment: @Grundy а можно ссылку на это дополнение?

Comment: например: https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Comment: @Grundy только что ее добавил и появился клон этой же ошибки + ругается на ту же строчку

Comment: добавлять ее надо, очевидно, между `jquery` и `main.js`

Comment: @Grundy так и сделал, безрезультатно.. =(

Comment: @Kron, без примера демонстрирующего ошибку, можно только гадать.

Comment: @Grundy выше в файле main.js в 4 строчке ошибка (Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function)

Comment: Пример выше работает если добавить плагин cookie, если у тебя не работает, значит ошибка где-то еще и предоставленной информации не хватает. Попробуй сделать [сниппет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999), чтобы можно было запустить код и проверить прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за развернутые ответы!